# define a shell function without a shell script in bash?

Tags: bash, shell

All I want to do is write and export a shell function without:

```
1) opening a file
2) editing it
3) saving it
4) running it
```

I'm aware of the implications... Something like:

`$ afunc () { echo "i am awesome" } && export -f afunc`

When i call afunc it will print "i am awesome" but if i try to do that I get this situation

```
$ afunc () { echo "aaa" }
>
```

Anyway way i can do this dynamically from stdin or something?

Comment: sorry about dupe, did not see those answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't a problem with being inside/outside a script, but a problem in how you're compressing your definition down to a one-liner: You need (but are not including) a semicolon before the closing brace.

The following works:

```
afunc () { echo "i am awesome"; } && export -f afunc
```